# Angular CLI post data wont reach api

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular-cli

I have a small problem with my Http Service in my Angular CLI app.
I have a form I need to submit. Data from this form are sent to API and stored into database.

This is the service

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    private api: string = "http://localhost/api/www/";
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    insertRouteReview(data: {}) {
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        });
        this.http.post(this.api+"route/addreview", data, {headers: headers});
    }
}
```

Data sample:

```
{
  "reviewId": 1,
  "userId": 1,
  "routeId": 1,
  "ratio": 3,
  "description": "lorem ipsumaaa"
}
```

Note: urlencoded is there before PHP cannot handle the application/json format.

When I send the data via some tool (For example Restlet Client) like this

[image]

The data are stored into DB successfully. So API should be fine.

What Am I doing wrong in my angular app? I get no error when I click the button which gets the data and pass them into http service.

E:

Code which is triggered after submit button is clicked

```
  onSubmit() {
  let review: {} = {
      reviewId: +this.reviewForm.value.reviewId,
      userId: +this.userService.userId,
      routeId: +this.routeId,
      ratio: +this.reviewForm.value.ratio,
      description: this.reviewForm.value.description
  };
  this.httpService.insertRouteReview(review);
```

}

The review form is just form created in typescript and its working fine. If I dump values (or review object) I can see the proper values.

E: I subscribed to the post and now Its working fine. Thank you

Comment: What's calling `insertRouteReview(data: {})` ?

Comment: Where are you subscribing to the post (the `insertRouteReview` function)?

Comment: I added the function which triggers the post action. R.Richards there is need to subscribe even if its post? I just need to reload page (so I can call NgOnInit() again and I should download the new data).

Comment: you should not call it Angular cli app, Angular cli is a command line tool for creating angular apps.

Comment: From the ng docs on http request: *An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods.* This also applies to the deprecated Http, which you are still using.

Comment: You need to call the subscribe() method to make the request complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I **didn't subscribed** to that post() method. When I did it, I reached the API.